# User Setting Not Changed

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my xaml:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Selected, Converter={StaticResource SelectedTabConverter}}"
```

I added Console.WriteLine() in Convert() and ConvertBack() so I could see that they were doing what they were supposed to do. However, when I checked my setting before saving it in my OnExit(), I saw that the setting was not changed. I thought this binding was two-way and I changed anything to the UI should change the setting at the same time. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried adding Mode=TwoWay to the binding?

Comment: Yes, I did...it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's hard to tell what your problem is without reading your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14433150/1136211).

You have created a Settings object as a resource in your App's ResourceDictionary. There's no need to do that. Just bind to the static `Settings.Default` object like shown below (and correctly shown in the answer to your other question).

```
{Binding Path=Selected, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}
```

where the XML namespace `properties` references the `Properties` namespace of your application.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyHomework__MVVM_.Properties"
        ... >
```

Aside from that you should bind to the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property instead of SelectedItem. That way you would not need a converter at all.

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Selected, Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"
```

---

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154533/1136211).

Comment: Love to see people use `x:Static` in their XAML.

Comment: I should have put "+1" first for it to be clearer :) For instance, I make all my converters singletons, and use `x:Static` to reference them instead of the usual `StaticResource` mess.

Comment: Well, it wasn't my design to make `Settings.Default` a static property. It's just the standard way how setting are created in a WPF project and accessed in binding expressions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and thanks for the link. UpdateSourceTrigger is exactly what I needed to set to make this work...I have worked with it for a couple of times I can't believe it didn't come to me when I stumbled upon this problem.